# Possible to bundle tox test environments?

Tags: python, tox

Is it possible to bundle `tox` test environments together? Imagine I have the following `tox` config:

```
[tox]

[testenv:foo-bar]
skip_install = True
commands = python -c "print('foo-bar')"

[testenv:foo-baz]
skip_install = True
commands = python -c "print('foo-baz')"
```

The behavior I want is to invoke `tox -e foo` and this automatically invokes `foo-bar` and `foo-baz`. I've tried to use the [`depends`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-depends) setting:

```
[testenv:foo]
depends = foo-bar, foo-baz
commands = python -c "print('foo')"
```

Either I misunderstood its meaning or it is not working since this is my output of `tox -e foo` with an empty `setup.py`:

```
GLOB sdist-make: /home/user/testtox/setup.py
foo create: /home/user/testtox/.tox/foo
foo inst: /home/user/testtox/.tox/.tmp/package/1/UNKNOWN-0.0.0.zip
foo installed: UNKNOWN @ file:///home/user/testtox/.tox/.tmp/package/1/UNKNOWN-0.0.0.zip
foo run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='125196572'
foo run-test: commands[0] | python -c 'print('"'"'foo'"'"')'
foo
______________________________________ summary _______________________________________
  foo: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

Comment: Indeed, `tox-factor` is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Do you know why my try with `depends` did not work?

Comment: The _warning_ right below seems to explain it. Not sure why it works like that, but it seems to be intentional behavior.

Comment: Huh, you might be right. I was under the impression it just pulls the top level so can't build a hierarchy with `depends`. Apparently, you can only use `depends` if you invoke `tox` without selecting an environment. Thanks again :)